Where the money for the difference of appraisal and purchase price goes
If an appraisal is lower than purchase price and buyer pays that difference where does that money go? Towards principal? It just means the buyer has to have a bigger downpayment to cover original downpayment plus the appraisal to purchase price difference right?

The only appraisals that really matter are for mortgage, for insurance, and for real estate taxes

Remember that appraised value is only an EDUCATED OPINION on what the house might go for in the current market, based on what similar properties have sold for. It has little to do with whether the buyers who are interested in your place will offer less because they hope to negotiate you down, or more because they want to grab it before someone else does.
Appraisals can be wrong. Appraisals can be outdated. Appraisals don't reflect the market negotiations between sellers and buyers, which may result in the place selling for less.. or for more.
Note: In some places, purchase price may be taken as a de facto tax appraisal. By definition, the buyer thought it was worth what they paid for it, no comparison or guessing required. (But, no, that doesn't mean that if you give your kid the house "for $1 and other goods and services" the town will only tax the kid on $1 worth of property.)

If you buy a house for 100k and it's appraised value is 80k, your loan-to-value (which is a factor in loan approval, interest rate, and PMI) is calculated based on how much you borrow divided by the appraised value.  If you want to get to an 80% LTV to avoid PMI, for example, than you can only borrow 64k (80% of 80k), which means that your "down payment" (the amount you pay at closing) needs to be 36k. IF the appraised value were 100k, you'd only need to put down 20k. The extra 16k isn't "lost" - is just reduces how much you are borrowing.
So in a sense I guess it "goes to principal" since it reduces the amount you have to borrow.  Mathematically it would be the same as if you'd borrowed 100k and immediately made a 36k payment to principal.
You could also say it "goes to the seller" since you probably have to borrow less than the appraised amount at closing. However, nothing changes for the seller regardless of the appraisal - they get 100k at closing (less their closing costs). The only difference is how much of that comes from the bank and how much comes from the buyer.  But mathematically it would be the same as if you took out a loan on an 80k purchase with a 20% down payment (borrowing 64k) and gave an additional 20k to the seller.

People buy houses for more than their appraisals all the time. The money goes to the seller. If the buyer can't pay for the house entirely in cash, there is a mortgage, so some of the money to the seller actually comes from the mortgage provider, who the buyer repays over the next few decades.
A better question might be where does the money come from? If a house is appraised at 100K and you arrange a 75K mortgage and look happily at your 25k savings that you will use as a downpayment (plus whatever you need for closing and moving costs) you feel content. But then, despite the appraisal, you can't get it for 100K, you'll need 110K to buy it. The bank is not going to give you a larger mortgage - or at least not without you paying a LOT in PMI - so you need to find another 10K somewhere or else you can't buy this house.
What's more, many lenders strongly disapprove of you borrowing your downpayment, to the extent they make people sign things that none of the downpayment is borrowed. This may mean you have no way to find that 10K and have to refrain from offering to buy a house you can't afford. The true measure of whether you can afford a house is not what it's appraised at, but what you can buy it for. They are rarely identical.

An appraisal is just someone's estimate of what the house is worth given current market conditions. The value of an appraisal doesn't "go" anywhere because it is not actual money that is changing hands.
Look at it this way. Suppose you wanted to sell a toaster at a garage sale. You ask me what I think you could get for your toaster and I say, "Oh, about $5." When you hold the garage sale you actually sell it for $6. Where did the $1 difference go? It didn't go anywhere, because the $5 was not money that actually changed hands.
Yes, an appraisal on a house is more "serious" than my toaster example. A bank will use an appraisal to decide if they're willing to loan a buyer money to buy a house. Like if the bank's appraiser says the house is worth $100k but the seller is demanding $150k, the bank likely won't approve the mortgage. Some government agencies that are involved in home mortgages, like FHA and VA, won't approve a sale over the appraisal value. But that doesn't change the basic nature of an appraisal: it's just somebody's estimate of what the property is worth, it's not cash that is actually being paid from one party to another.
